# Eclipse > New File - option: link to the file in the file system

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I was creating a properties file for my project in eclipse. 
When I create the file i see a window with two fields "enter or select parent folder" and  "file name" and "advanced" button. Click that button and you see the option "link to the file in the file system ". What does this mean and what does it do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create a reference of a file in your file-system as a file in your project.

But when you package it (for example JAR or WAR) for distribution, the referred file will be copied and package with it.

Answer (score 0):

Its like opening that file in eclipse.